# why did I get the same two ids when using id() function on two different indexes of a pytorch tensor?

Tags: python, memory, pytorch

```
a = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
print(id(a[0]))
print(id(a[1]))
```

When I execute the code above, I get the following same two results:

```
2203226175040
2203226175040
```

I do know that two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value, but shouldn't these two tensors a[0] and a[1] exist together?

Comment: I don’t know torch, but if `a[..]` returns a dynamically instantiated object on the fly, that’d explain the behavior.

Comment: `a[..]` is `2D` tensor and your are accessing its elements